# Dajaxice function not callable error after initial setup

Tags: python, django, dajaxice, dajax

I just set up Django and Dajaxice and I am having trouble getting it to work after closely checking the documentation for both Django set up and Dajaxice.

After some research here at stack overflow the only thing I found was to make sure that I had dajaxice_autodiscover() in my urls.py, which I do. Here is my ajax.py in my TimeBlendApp:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register


@dajaxice_register
def sayhello(request):
return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello World'})
```

and my html page

```
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function my_js_callback(data){
            alert(data.message);
        }
    </script>
    <title>My base template</title>
    {% dajaxice_js_import %}
  </head>
  <body>
  <button onclick="Dajaxice.TimeBlendApp.sayhello(my_js_callback);">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error I get is

```
FunctionNotCallableError at /dajaxice/TimeBlendApp.sayhello/
TimeBlendApp.sayhello
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dajaxice/TimeBlendApp.sayhello/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: FunctionNotCallableError
Exception Value:    
TimeBlendApp.sayhello
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dajaxice\views.py in dispatch, line  60
```

Answer (score 2):

You must run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

everytime you change or add the dajax/dajaxice functions.So dajaxice can create its own javascript libraries in static directory.